# html source showing extra <p> tags

Tags: html

here you will see  duration:50hrs.Now if you debug this using firebug, you will see extra `<p></p>` tags after 50 hrs, whereas in actual html i made "duration:50 hrs" inside p tags

Please point out the reason.

Comment: Can you paste the HTML and the resulting DOM here, please? We don't want to click on random links.

Comment: @gauravoberoi have to pasted the html via any editor or its raw HTML..paste your HTML here

Answer (score 2):

It is not valid to have an `<h2>` (or any other block-level element) inside a `<p>` tag. Consider using a `<div>` tag with margins instead.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, should be a commment

Comment: Actually, it does answer the question. If you want specifics, though, the "extra" `<p>` tags are the browser trying to "correct" the invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspecting the element I saw

```
<p>The course offered by us cover complete and thorough knowledge of Search Engine Optimization, which is essential for the success of online business, Knowledge and understanding of the workings of search engines and the SEO skills that the course develops ensures clear understanding of Search Engine Optimization.
This course gives hands-on experience in the area of Search Engine Optimization and internet marketing.</p>
<p><h2 class="reqmnts">Duration:</h2> 50 Hrs</p>
<p><h2 class="reqmnts">Pre-requisite:</h2> Basic Knowledge of computer & internet</p>
```

This is not what you described, as the `<p>` tags are placed in an order

```
 <p><h2 class="reqmnts">Duration:</h2> 50 Hrs</p>
 <p><h2 class="reqmnts">
```

as you can see, on the second line there is a `<p>` at the start, wich is in acordance to the ending `<p>`

If the error is this neat then :)

To fix the error you will need to remove the `<p>` tags aroung the text and simply add a `<br>` wich will separate the two lines